# MariaDB после запуска не пускает обратно в bash

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, mariadb

Поставил на тестовый сервер (он на ноутбуке с Puppyrus-a linux) MariaDB. Он запускался нормально, и поэтому я добавил его в автозапуск (rc.local). Но при очередном запуске произошло следующее:

```
$sudo mysqld -u root
```

```
...
[Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 195884 and 1958844 in idbata files do not match the log sequence number 1958864 in the ib_logfiles!
[Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
...
[Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
...
[Note] InnoDB: Crash recovery finished.
...
Version: '10.0.15-MariaDB-log' socket:'/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port:3306 MariaDB Server
```

И все. Пустая строка, в баш не пускает ни под каким предлогом. Перепробовал кучу комбинаций клавиш - ничего не работает.
Комп спас, убрал строку из автозапуска. При запуске скрипта через telnet происходит то же самое, я просто прерываю сессию, а сервер продолжает работать. Кто-нибудь знает решение?

Comment: прервать выполнение программы можно нажатием `ctrl+c`. только зачем вы запускаете ещё один экземпляр демона, раз первый у вас запускается при старте?

Comment: видимо спутал с просто mysql

Comment: @alexander По ctrl-c не закрывается. mysqld я убрал из автозапуска.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov  Не спутал с MySQL. mysql Как раз нормально работает, закрывается.

Comment: Ctrl-Z попробуйте нажать. Приостановит и поместит задачу в фон. Вернуть обратно - командой fg.

Comment: @MAH69K ctrl-z не работает. Выводит просто ^Z и ничего не происходит. Я же написал, перепробовал много комбинаций клавиш, перед вопросом на stackoverflow гуглил. Ответа так и не нашел

Comment: Переустановить, видимо файловая система попортилась.

Comment: @sergw Переустановил линукс. Не помогло. Я предполагаю, что где-то в многочисленных опциях находится одна, которая запустит демона в фоне. Пойду копаться в опциях.